# Two Selenium instances opening on running app

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

My driver code is as follows-

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = Options()
    # options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")    
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--disable-software-rasterizer")
    options.add_argument("user-agent=Chrome/42.0.2311.135")
    options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    # options.add_argument("--start-fullscreen")

    default_directory = os.getcwd()

    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        "download.default_directory": default_directory,
        "download.prompt_for_download": False,
        "download.directory_upgrade": True,
        "safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled": False,
        "safebrowsing.enabled": False
        }
    )
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.getcwd() + "\\chromedriver.exe", options=options) # For Local only
    # driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options) # For Docker only
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port='5000', debug=True)
    # app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='5000', debug=True)
```

The code works fine, but the issue is that upon calling the Driver code, two instances of selenium are opened. All API hits are reflected on one browser window, whereas the other browser (instance) is just of no use. I can't figure out why this second window is opening up. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

P.S. I am not initiating a new instance in any other part of my code

Comment: We miss your workflow, we dont know how you call or how you run it

Comment: @Wonka this is the first piece of code which is responsible for starting a session. Also I seemed to have figured out the issue. Flask app restarts in debug mode which causes the instance to launch again. Upon making "debug=False", only 1 instance opens.